# How to pass a generated string to an EditText?

Tags: java, android

Through a button, I create an alphanumeric string. This string that I just created, I want it to be inserted in an edit text in the same Activity where there is the same button. 
The button's method:

```
generateCodButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            Random rand = new Random();
            StringBuffer tempStr = new StringBuffer();
            tempStr.append("");
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                int c = rand.nextInt(122 - 48) + 48;
                if((c >= 58 && c <= 64) || (c >= 91 && c <= 96))
                {
                    i--;
                    continue;
                }
                tempStr.append((char)c);
            }
            String code = tempStr.toString();
        }
    });
```

So I want to pass the var "code" to an editText for read the string (in the same Activity). How can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I want it to be inserted in an edit text*

Looks like you want to change your editText text, if that's the case you can just do it with `setText` method:

```
editText.setText(code);
```